# Bash: Looping over multiple input sources (nesting "while read" loops?)

Tags: bash

I have a `query.sh` script which runs `dig` commands, performing a set of lookups from different DNS servers, which are currently given in a column in the single input file used (`sites.txt`).

My goal is to modify this script to use a different input file, `dns_servers.txt`, to find the DNS servers to iterate through for each query.

I'm not clear on where to start here. What do I need to do to be able to safely nest `while read` loops?

---

### Current inputs:

#### query.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line;
do
        set $line
        echo "SITE:" $1@$2
        /usr/sbin/dig +short -4 @$2 $1
        sleep 5
        exitStatus=$?
        echo "Exit Status: " $exitStatus
done < sites.txt
```

#### sites.txt

Current format has a hostname and a DNS server to use for lookups against that hostname.

```
www.google.com 8.8.4.4
```

The intent is for the column with the DNS server to be ignored, and the contents of `dns_servers.txt` to be used instead.

---

### Desired Inputs

#### dns_servers.txt

```
10.1.1.1
12.104.1.232
...
```

Comment: Also, `set $line` is very, very buggy (look at what happens if `site.txt` contains a line with `*`). Use a real array, and `read -r -a` instead. Though, for only two items, you don't even need that: `while read -r site_name destination_ip` will put what's currently `$1` in `site_name` and what's currently `$2` in `destination_ip`.

Comment: `while read name ip;`, then drop the `set` command and use `$name` and `$ip` in place of `$1` and `$2`. Also, `exitStatus` is the exit status of `sleep`, not `dig`; you need to save the value of `$?` immediately after the command whose status you want.

Comment: BTW, your tag is `bash`, but your shebang is `#!/bin/sh`. Bash scripts must use `#!/bin/bash`; the shebang `#!/bin/sh` is for POSIX sh, and any script using it is not guaranteed to have access to features not promised in the POSIX shell specification.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest running your scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing errors that finds before presenting them here.

Comment: The intent of the script was to verify that no matter wherever the user is located, he is be able to Query Websites and the websites perform correct DNS lookup.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of running an other command instead of dig with different destination IPs set i.e running Query from a source server to a several destination servers and later decided to go with dig. That's the reason there is an extra column in the site.txt file

Comment: I've tried to improve the question further; the one thing it's still missing is a statement of what you've already tried (that covers how you tried to add the missing functionality, ie. reading both files), but otherwise I think it's getting into a reasonable state.

Comment: Since the sites.txt file had both the columns, hostname and DNS server, I didn't require another file to execute my script. But later when the number of DNS servers increased, it became difficult to iterate each dns_server through each query every time using just this one file. Hence I decided to use two different files one with just hostnames and one with all dns_servers and loop over multiple input files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ignoring any additional column(s) in the `sites.txt` file, and iterating through the lines of `dns_servers.txt`, might look like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r site _ <&3; do
  while read -r dns_server <&4; do
    dig +short -4 "@$dns_server" "$site"; exit=$?
    sleep 5
    echo "Exit status: $exit"
  done 4<dns_servers.txt
done 3<sites.txt
```

The key changes here:

- Pass the list of fields you want to parse as arguments to `read`. The underscore passed as second positional argument to the first `read` is the variable name to which the second column of `site.txt` is now being saved.
- Nest your loops, since you want to read from the inner loop for every pass of the outer loop.
- Use a different file descriptor (here, `3` and `4`) for outer and inner loops to keep them separated.

---

Incidentally, if you were targeting bash (`#!/bin/bash`) rather than POSIX sh (`#!/bin/sh`), I might do this differently. The below uses the bash 4 extension `mapfile` to read `dns_servers.txt` all at once:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t dns_servers <dns_servers.txt
while read -r site _; do
  for from_ip in "${dns_servers[@]}"; do
    dig +short -4 "@$from_ip" "$site"; exit=$?
    sleep 5
    echo "Exit status: $exit"
  done
done <sites.txt
```

Here, we read `dns_servers.txt` only once, and reuse that list of values for each value read from `sites.txt`.

If you're using bash 3.x, `mapfile` can be replaced with a loop:

```
dns_servers=( )
while read -r; do dns_servers+=( "$REPLY" ); done <dns_servers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. The first fix worked. Second one gave me a readarray: command not found error, but that was because of the old bash version.

Comment: The output also was as expected.

Comment: Thanks Charles for editing the Question. It seems that the entire format of the question was messed up after posting.

Comment: I'm no longer afraid of nested loops in Bash! But now it seems I need to learn about file descriptors to really grok it.