# Nested while read loops with fd

Tags: bash, shell, loops, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I'm trying to read from two different inputs in nested loops without success. I've followed the best answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31791324/bash-looping-over-multiple-input-sources-nesting-while-read-loops) and also took a look at the [file descriptors page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) of the *Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide*.

### Sample script I made to test my problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line <&3 ; do
    echo $line
    while read _line <&4 ; do
        echo $_line
    done 4< "sample-2.txt"
done 3< "sample-1.txt"
```

### Content of sample-1.txt

```
Foo
Foo
```

### Content of sample-2.txt

```
Bar
Bar
```

### Expected output

```
Foo
Bar
Bar
Foo
Bar
Bar
```

### The output I get

```
Foo
Bar
```

Comment: I get the expected output in both `bash` 3.2.57 and 4.4.12. I suspect your text files do not have a newline character at the end of the final line.

Comment: @Lapsusone, ...btw, the ABS is not a particularly well-regarded reference; it's rather infamous for showcasing bad practices in its examples. Consider the wooledge wiki (ie. [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), which covers your problem explicitly in the "My text files are broken!" section), or the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/).

Comment: Oh yes I have been using bash-hackers wiki and liked it a lot. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text files do not end with newlines:

```
$ printf 'Foo\nFoo' > sample-1.txt
$ printf 'Bar\nBar' > sample-2.txt
$ bash tmp.sh
Foo
Bar
$ printf '\n' >> sample-1.txt
$ printf '\n' >> sample-2.txt
$ bash tmp.sh
Foo
Bar
Bar
Foo
Bar
Bar
```

`read` has a non-zero exit status if it reaches the end of the file without seeing a newline character. There's a hack to work around that, but it's better to ensure that your text files correctly end with a newline character.

```
# While either read is successful or line is set anyway
while read line <&3 || [[ $line ]]; do
```