# Nested while loop to copy string from one file to another file

Tags: loops, nested, zsh, paste

I am new to `shell` and usually using single line commands. However, I would like to learn more in `bash` but got stuck with this problem of looping.

I have two file- `A` and `B`. I would like to paste `A` (one line at a time) to file `B` when it find pattern `("Hit")` and so on. Here is the example.

**file A:**

```
contig543
conting432
conting32
```

**file B:**

```
Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167       
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126       
                
Hit     E-value 
WP_0134644.1  0       
WP_0134625.1  2.53E-108  

Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167       
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126
```

**Output file:**

```
contig543

Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167       
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126 

contig432

Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167       
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126 

contig32

Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167       
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126
```

**here is my code:**

```
#!/bin/zsh
  
fileA='contig1'
n=1
while read line; do
# reading each line
   echo "$line"

   fileB='F3.txt'
   x=1
   while read line1; do
      echo "$line1"
      if [["$line1" = ^"Hit"]]; then
         echo "$line1"
      fi
   done < $fileB
done < $fileA
n=$((n+1))
```

Comment: I wasn't completely sure about your file spacing, but you can edit if I missed the blank likes. You will see how I formatted the blocks as fixed text when you do.

Comment: Note, you need to use different file-descriptors for your different loops, see [Nested while read loops with fd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559013/nested-while-read-loops-with-fd) and there are many more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Start with shellcheck.net for syntax errors.
(I'm using bash - I need to compare zsh syntax...)

The root of your problem is here: `[["$line1" = ^"Hit"]]`
You need spaces inside the `[[` and `]]`, and a tilde on your operator. I'd also *remove* the quotes on your pattern here; they technically aren't a problem, but they are a complication you don't need in this case. The result:

```
[[ "$line1" =~ ^Hit ]]
```

The other problem is that this is going to read and print out ALL of F3.txt for every entry in contig1, echoing the contig1 value at the top each time, and then just double-printing the `Hit` lines. You need to interleave and coordinate your data, so it needs more logic. Likewise, you aren't using `x` and `n`; why are they there?

Fortunately, there are simpler and more efficient solutions.
A quick hack, focusing on just fixing the loop logic:

```
set -- $(<A)                            # A to arg array
while read b                            # read each line of B (c.f. "done<B")
do case "$b" in                         # string match the line
   Hit*) printf "%s\n\n%s\n" $1 "$b"    # print formatted on match
         shift                       ;; # remove the used value from A
      *) echo "$b"                   ;; # for anything else, just print it
   esac
done<B                                  # set input on the loop
```

This makes a lot of unchecked assumptions, such as that you don't need $@ for something else, that there are an appropriate number of record in A for groups in B, that values in A have no inappropriate characters such as whilespaces that would throw off the array load (note I didn't quote $1 either), that both A & B have newlines at the end of the last line, and a good bit more... but depending on your situation, those might be reasonably safe assumptions. If they are not, please edit accordingly.

It *avoids* the nested loop which reads all of B for every value in A, though.
This loads A into a sequential queue and shifts off the next element to collate into your output of B each time you "Hit" the trigger string.

If you want a *slightly* less quick & dirty version that still reads through each file only once, accounts for possible whitespace in the keys of A, does less haphazard reads, and uses pattern matching as your were doing:

```
aLst=()
while read -r a  || # by-line raw read of A
      [[ -n "$a" ]] # allowing for no newline on last record
do aLst+=("$a")     # quoted assignment into named indexed array
done<A 
while read -r b || [[ -n "$b" ]]                # safer read like A
do if [[ "$b" =~ ^Hit ]]                        # check for trigger string
   then printf "%s\n\n%s\n" "${aLst[0]}" "$b"   # quoted element access
        aLst=( "${aLst[@]:1}" )                 # "shift" for arrays
   else echo "$b"                               # just print nonmatches
   fi
done<B
```

Output of both:

```
contig543

Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126

conting432

Hit     E-value
WP_0134644.1  0
WP_0134625.1  2.53E-108

conting32

Hit     E-value
WP_0134620.1  1.63E-167
WP_0134619.1  7.31E-126
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Thank you Paul. I appreciate your help. It is really well explained.

Comment: Accept the solution? Maybe upvote too, lol ;)