# Echo to a line above the line where there is a specific string

Tags: bash

I am using a `for f in $(cat /dir/file)` nested loop with a conditional inside it to test `if (($f=$z))`, `z` being in the `for z in $(cat /dir/file2)` loop, where the `f` loop is nested.
I want to know if its possible to write to the line above the line where the `$z` string is in `file2`, if `$z=$f`.
each line in `file2` is a 5 digit number like 07732, if there a line with 07732 in `file` I want to write that line above the line where that 07732 in file 2 is

What I've got right now is

```
for z in $(cat /dir/file2)
do
  for f in $(cat /dir/file)
    do
    if (( $f=$z ))
    then
    (what im asking about)
    i=0
    break
    else
    i=1
    fi
  done
if ((i=1))
then
......
```

I know I've got syntax errors no need to correct those.
Sorry if I'm explaining it really poorly, please tell me if I need to explain in more detail

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Instead, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: ...and yes, a [mcve] with sample input and expected output (and code that's complete enough that someone else can run it themselves to test their answers without changing anything *except* fixing the narrow problem) would be a big help.

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that UNIX filesystem semantics don't let you directly insert content partway through a file *at all*, without rewriting that content and everything below it (generally -- there are some exceptions, but they require specialized filesystems and only let you insert large block-sized chunks at block-aligned offsets); barring extensions, you can only replace parts of a file in-place with content of the exact same length if you don't want to rewrite. This is why tools like `sed -i` create a whole new temporary file with your edits, and then rename it over the original.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the text of your question.

Comment: Where do `$b` and `$o` come from?

Comment: BTW, re: "I know I've got syntax errors" -- a good [mre] is *reproducible*; it's correct enough someone can run it and see **only** your specific error, so they only need to fix that one error to get a successful test run, not that one error plus however many others there are. (It also includes sample inputs and outputs; in this case, that means examples of `file` and `file2`, and an example of the output those copies of `file` and `file2` should generate).

Comment: please ask a question, I can't see one in your post. That's why it's on hold, I believe

Comment: dennis answered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delay the output of the matched line. And, as Charles Duffy pointed out in a commend, don't read lines with `for`. Also note that you will be reading the entire file2 *for each line of file1*. If file2 is of any significant size, this could bne very slow. If file2 is pretty small, read it into an array.

Also you should use meaningful variable names. This isn't 1970's BASIC where you are restricted to single characters.

Here is some sample code that incorporates most of that but leaves the inner while loop in place instead of using an array:

```bash
while read -r file1_line
do
    while read -r -u 3 file2_line
    do
        if [[ $file2_line == $file1_line ]]
        then
            echo "some special putput"
            i=0
            break
        else
            i=1
        fi
    done 3< /path/to/file2
    echo "NOW I'm echoing $file1_line"
    if (( i == 1 ))
    then
        . . .
    fi
done < /path/to/file1
```

This will echo the lines from file one, but when there's a match it will echo a string before the matched line.

The inner `while` loop uses an [additional file descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791521/26428) in order to be able to read from a second file while the outer loop is reading from the STDIN file descriptor. This is so that multiple files can be read independently at the same time. The `-u 3` tells `read` to use file descriptor 3. The `3<` redirection puts the contents of file2 on file descriptor 3 so they can be read there.

Comment: In `(( ))`, you need `==` for comparison. `=` assigns.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Thanks, I just copy/pasted the OP's code fixing the main issue and failed to notice that. Fixed.

Comment: `file2` redirected to `fd3` may warrant a sentence to explain how you are able to process two different input streams in the nested `while` loops. (that part is probably bewildering to new bash users)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: good idea

Comment: in your description you say that i have to delay the output of the matched line, could you explain whats doing that in your code. Also is everything under the file_line comparison delayed , like head or tail , or just something like an echo

Comment: @Letho123: The second `echo` (the one after the `if` block) is the delayed output. Any other processing including the output of the marker line is done within the `if` block. Note that nothing is really "delayed" as much as it's just done _after_. Anything can be done after the `if` block that you might need. Note that it's possible that other methods might be better suited to what you might be trying to do, but my answer is a solution to what you asked in your question.

Comment: ok i understand what your saying ,thanks