# Recursive find and use partial file path for output and more commands

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure with several levels, and on some of the directories there are files name "file1.txt"

I am trying to write a script to find the files, and write their paths (separated by spaces instead of '/') as well as grep some information for inside the file.

I thought a combination of `find`, `while` loops and `read` commands were the way to go, but now I'm not so sure.

The idea was to `find` the files, and write the list to a variable.
Then go through that viable one line at a time and get the file path and the text from inside and write to an output file.

My best attempt is:

```
#!/bin/bash
outputf='output.dat'
printf "some_text1 some_text2 some_text3 some_text4\n" > "$outputf"
FILE="$(find . -iname "file1.txt" -print0)"

while IFS= read -r -d  '' LINE ; do
    while IFS="/" read -ra PARTS ; do \
        for i in "${PARTS[@]}" ; do
            printf '%s ' "$i" >> "$outputf"
        done
        # grep "some text" $FILE >> "$outputf"
        printf "\n" >> "$outputf"
    done  <<< "$LINE"
done <<< "$FILE"
```

Unfortunately, I only get the output from the first `printf` command.

I was expecting to get something like the following

```
some_text1 some_text2 some_text3 some_text4
. path_to_file1 file1.dat sometext
. path_to_file2 file1.dat sometext
. path_to_file3 file1.dat sometext
. path_to_file4 file1.dat sometext
```

However, I can't even get the file path to write to the output file (hence why the `grep` command is commented).

Comment: `printf stuff; find -name file1.txt | xargs awk '/some text/ { f=FILENAME; gsub("/"," ",f); print f,$0 }'`

Comment: @jhnc I think that does it! And it's a lot simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: nested `read` loops need to use different file descriptors.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Sorry, I'm not understanding what you mean, could you please elaborate?

Comment: [Nested `read` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791521/26428).